# Tensorflow: Evaluation of Binary Classifier with Unbalanced Data with metric tf.metrics.recall_at_thresholds

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to evaluate a binary classifier trained on unbalanced data, in Tensorflow, and have problems using **tf.metrics.recall_at_thresholds**

```
one_hot_targets=tf.reshape(tf.one_hot(tf.cast(Y,tf.int32),2),[-1,2]) #Y are labels
weights=tf.reshape(tf.transpose(tf.matmul(one_hot_targets,tf.transpose([[ratio,1.0-ratio]]))),[-1,1])
recalls=tf.metrics.recall_at_thresholds(labels=Y,predictions=func_8,thresholds=[0.2,0.3,0.4,0.6,0.7],weights=weights)
```

but this gives me the following error in `Session.run()`:

```
Attempting to use uninitialized value recall_at_thresholds/true_positives
     [[Node: recall_at_thresholds/true_positives/read = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@recall_at_thresholds/true_positives"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](recall_at_thresholds/true_positives)]]
```

Pleas note that both **ratio** and **Y** are passed using the *feed dict* in session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you dint initialized the local and global variables associated

```
sess.run([tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer()])
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick fix! much appreciated.